# What is the syntax for a subshell in eshell?

Tags: eshell, shell, subprocess

How to write the analogue of a bash-command like:

```
(cd ../repo && git fast-export master) | darcs convert import repo_master
```

in eshell?

Here a subshell is employed to restrict the effect of `cd`.

Answer (score 3):

In `eshell`, process subshells are generally done with `${...}` syntax. However, the output is produced in the form of an intermediate Emacs Lisp expression.

```
~ $ echo ${cd ~/.emacs.d; ls} | cat
("README.md" "ac-comphist.dat"
  #("auto-save-list" 0 14
     (font-lock-face eshell-ls-directory))
  #("bin" 0 3
     (font-lock-face eshell-ls-directory))
  "custom.el"
[more text omitted]
```

While this is useful if you want to chain Elisp expression, it is not if you want to pass a raw string. Instead, you might want to use the command `eshell-command-result`.

```
~ $ echo (substring-no-properties (eshell-command-result "cd ~/.emacs.d; ls")) | cat
README.md
ac-comphist.dat
auto-save-list
bin
custom.el
[more text omitted]
```

Various modifications may help you get what you want. Just play with it and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting! I have a question about `${}`. How is it supposed to be used? Normally, elisp expressions dont't read stdin, so one must invent something complex after a `${...} |`, true?

Comment: By experimenting, I found out more about `{ }` (behaves similarly to `${ }`) -- http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7688/5165 . Among other things, if the thing inside `{ }` is not a builtin, then the output is never an elisp expression. So can use it for example safely. I don't know how `{ }` and `${ }` differ.

Answer (score 2):

`{ ... }` has very varying behavior (at least, from the point of view of bash):

```
~ $ {echo a b c} | tr [[:lower:]] [[:upper:]]
("A" "B" "C")~ $ 
~ $ {echo hi} | tr [[:lower:]] [[:upper:]]
HI~ $ {/bin/echo a b c} | tr [[:lower:]] [[:upper:]]
~ $ A B C

~ $ echo {echo a b c}
("a" "b" "c")
~ $ echo {/bin/echo a b c}
~ $ echo {/bin/echo hi}
~ $ echo {echo hi}
hi
~ $ echo ${/bin/echo hi}
~ $
```

As you can see:

- **a builtin** inside `{ }` feeds its output to a pipe AND provides it as the substitution when used as an argument of a command. Another peculiarity is that:

  - if the output consists of **one "element"**, it is output in its bare form,
  - but **a list** is output as an elsip list.
- A **Unix program** inside `{ }` feeds its output to a pipe AND NEVER makes it a substitution in an argument position. There is also no special treatment of lists, no elisp expressions appear as the output.

I'm not sure whether **`${ }`** does exactly the same as `{ }` or there are some differences...

Comment: It looks like the dollar sign is there so you can use it in a string. Namely, you can do `cd /a/${echo b}/c`. If you're using it as its own word, the dollar sign is not needed.